# Is there a way to view a site from a web browser's cache?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, browser-cache

A website I saw on my local network recently appears to have gone down. I don't have control over the device that serves the site, so I can't simply bring it back up or troubleshoot it directly myself.

Right now, I just need to be able to see what I saw when I last viewed the site. Assuming the data hasn't been purged yet, is there an easy way to re-create the site from my browser's cache?

The browser in this particular case is Firefox 31. For future reference, answers for Chrome and Internet Explorer are also of interest. (Should those be separate questions?)

Answer (score 2):

If your cache has not been cleared, and has not had files deleted due to exceeding space limitation, you can see each part of the web page, though not necessarily as it looked at the time you saw it. In the URL bar, type **about:cache* and click on *List Cache Entries*.  If you click on an HTML file (extension .htm or .html), it should call up most of the page in cache (*first disconnect from the internet to prevent refreshing to the current page*).

An alternative is to use Google's *cached* view of a site or the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/). An acquaintance restored a client's web site using cached pages from Google (of course, that only fetched static information).

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: As stated, this is a site on a LAN - Archive.org is of no use. And I'm aware I can browse through the files in the cache, but the question here is really looking for a simple "show me the site" interface.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: There's a search engine and page store for your browser, i.e. saves everything you visit.

Though Mac OS X only, and I haven't tried it and do not exactly recommend it (it's not saved in the cloud, but you still have to trust the vendor - not open source), but it reflects an idea I've had a couple of years ago.

http://fetching.io/native/

Maybe someone wants to push forward an open source project like this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Firefox will load pages from the cache in offline mode.

- To enable offline mode, open the main menu, select **Developer**, and check **Work offline**. (If the Developer button isn't there, click on **Customize** and add it to the menu.)
- Where available, pages will load from the cache. They will not load from the network until you disable offline mode.